# How can i gzip or deflate my facebook like.php's?

Tags: facebook-like, gzip, deflate, google-pagespeed

i check my homepage via google pagespeed test.

it suggest this with high priority:
you should compress facebook like.php inquiries via gzip or deflate method.
http://www.facebook.com/plugin/like.php?share=false&show_faces=false&width=45

do you have any idea, how can i do this?

note: i have these codes on my **.htaccess** file.

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|html|css|js)$">
FileETag INode MTime Size
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fix that on your server. That resource is served directly from facebook.com and they need to configure their site to use gzip. You could try contacting Facebook to report the problem, but that's the best that you can do.

Comment: Any idea why they don't compress those files in the first place? Seems like an obvious thing to do.

Comment: Probably they just haven't noticed this yet. You'd have to ask them.